# How do I find 20 odd numbers starting from a number entered by user?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop

So, i was given an assignment to find 20 odd numbers starting from a number entered by user.. I know how to find odd numbers. but I don't know how to find them starting from a number entered by user.

I tried this:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num,i;
    cout<<"Enter num:   ";
    cin>>num;
    for(i=num;i<=20;i++){
        if(i%2!=0)
        cout<<num <<endl;
    }
}
```

but it outputs the number entered by user 20 times.

Comment: Well, you output `num`, not `i`.

Comment: Just put in ```i <= num+20``` in the middle parameter of the for loop.

Comment: edit if i write cout<<i instead of cout<<num, it gives the output of odd numbers, but it doesn't give 20 odd numbers

Comment: @A.Franzen yes but it doesn't output 20 numbers

Comment: Also since a number over two is odd, you need to go up to about `num + 40` and then figure out if you always get 20 numbers and make necessary adjustments. Really simple mathematics left to the user...

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, you output the `num`, not newly calculated `i`, but even if you fix that, you will output only few odd numbers (or none), for example for input 50 there will be no output instead of odd 20 numbers (because `50 <= 20` is always false, so no `for` body will be executed). Plus you are doing lot of math... while the whole task can collapse to trivial:

```
#include<iostream>
int main() {
    int num;
    std::cout << "Enter num:   ";
    std::cin >> num;
    num |= 1;   // turn user number into odd one (if it was even)
    const int endNum = num + 20*2;  // calculate the first odd number after 20 of them (end value)
    while (num < endNum) {
        std::cout << num << std::endl;
        num += 2;
    }
}
```

doing just simple addition +2 in loop.

edit: btw, why `num |= 1;` guarantees odd number... because integers in computer are stored as binary values, where every digit is different power of two, with the least significant bit corresponding to the zeroth power of two (i.e. value 1). If this bit is set, then the value is odd, because dividing by two does apply from first power of two upward and this bottom bit is remainder. And if it is reset, the value is even, for the same reason, the bottom bit is remainder after you would divide the value by two. The binary or operator `|= 1` will set the least significant bit to one, turning any integer value to odd one.

This is the special case, when your task involves calculation based on powers of two. Because all the values in computer are already encoded in the binary way, there are usually shortcuts how to get the result of such calculation. Like for example to get remainder of division by 16 from integer `n` you can do binary and: `n & 15` and you have the remainder. Or to divide by 16 you can shift the unsigned integer value by four bits to the right like `n >> 4` to get the result. But this doesn't work with calculations which are not power-of-two based, i.e. remainder after dividing by ten is NOT `n & 9`, because 9 is 0b1001, so different values will be trimmed down to only values 0, 1, 8 or 9, but remainders after dividing by 10 can be any value from 0 to 9. .. while 15 is in binary `0b1111`, so such binary and-mask will produce all values from 0 to 15, and they correspond to the remainder by div 16.

Comment: While your explanation is really good, other answer code is simpler to read.

Comment: Well the bit trick only work for positive number. This is a micro-optimization and it make the code harder to read for one that does not understand bits

Comment: yes and yes (intentionally).

Answer (score 1):

The bug in your code is that you print `num` instead of `i`. So just do:

```
    cout<< i <<endl;
           ^
```

But you can simplify your code a lot by doing:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int num,i;
    cout<<"Enter num:   ";
    cin>>num;
    if (num%2 == 0) ++num;            // Make sure num is odd
    for(i=0; i < 20; ++i){            // Print 20 numbers
        cout << (num + 2*i) << endl;  // Multiply i by 2 and add it to num
                                      // so that the result is the next odd number
    }
}
```

**note**

As suggested by Ped7g the line

```
    if (num%2 == 0) ++num; // Make sure num is odd
```

can be made more simple. Just replace it with

```
    num |= 1;  // Set the least significant bit so that num is odd
```

Comment: The suggestion make the code harder to read as you need to understand bits and not only basic math. This is micro optimisation that a good compiler is probably able to figure out. Also, the first one works with negative numbers but not the second

Comment: I would have preferred: `for(int i=0; i < 20; ++i) { cout<< (num + 2 * i) << endl; }` though.

Comment: `int i` should be declared in the `for` loop for best possible code

Comment: @Phil1970 that was kinda the point of my answer... to open the OP's mind and show him there are things beyond basic math, which he maybe should be aware of, if he wants to program... ... .or maybe I'm just showing off... probably the later... sigh. :) sry. :)

Answer (score 1):

This loop

```
for(i=num;i<=20;i++){
    if(i%2!=0)
    cout<<num <<endl;
}
```

does not make sense because it checks the variable `i` instead of the variable `num` whether it is an odd number. And it is obvious there will be outputted a half of `20` values of `i`.

The program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 20;

    int n = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";

    std::cin >> n;

    n |= 1;   // make the first odd number

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << n << ' ';

        n += 2;
    }
}
```

Its output might look the following way

```
Enter a number: 10
11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49
```

A more correct professional code can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 20;

    int n = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter a number: ";

    std::cin >> n;

    n |= 1;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        std::cout << n << ' ';

        n = std::numeric_limits<int>::max() - 2 < n ? std::numeric_limits<int>::min() | 1 : n + 2;
    }
}
```

In this case if the user will enter the maximum integer value then the output will look like

```
Enter a number: 2147483647
2147483647 -2147483647 -2147483645 -2147483643 -2147483641 -2147483639 -2147483637 -2147483635 -2147483633 -2147483631 -2147483629 -2147483627 -2147483625 -2147483623 -2147483621 -2147483619 -2147483617 -2147483615 -2147483613 -2147483611
```

Comment: At least, your answer use a constant and thus follow the DRY principle.